# How to make a .cat file from a .txt file

Tags: windows-7-x64, cat, text-analysis

I'm having trouble in converting a .txt file into a .cat file.

It's a dictionary (LIWC2007 italian)which separates words into categories; I have to load it on WordStat 6.1. WordStat won't see any non-.cat files when I try to load the dictionary.

How do I convert the file? Looking on the web wasn't helpful.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you need to change the format/content of the file, or just the name?

Comment: this isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'ren' command. So ren filename.txt filename.cat.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what OS you are on but on windows you can open the command prompt and use the move command to rename the file with the *.cat extention something like this should work move myfile.txt myfile.cat this may still not work however if the program is looking for more than just the extension.